# Debian Linux script. Restart MongoDB

Tags: linux, mongodb, shell, debian, sh

Help write the SH script that can be hung on CRON. The script should check whether MongoDB, if not, delete the file mongod.lock and restart the mongo server.

```
if (mongo == down) {
# rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
# /etc/init.d/mongodb restart
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first experience of writing bash script. Here are some options to get at me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function now_time() {
    date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
}

function logging() {
    echo "`now_time` [$1] $2" >> /var/mongoRestart.log
}

A=`/etc/init.d/mongodb status`

if [[ $A == "Checking status of database: mongodb running." ]]; then
  echo 'true'
else
  rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
  /etc/init.d/mongodb restart
  logging FALSE 'mongodb down' 
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to run this script on the same machine, which is hosting mongodb then use `nc` command with `-z` parameter to check whether mongodb is listening on port 27017, if not it will ru it after repairing.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 if ! nc -z localhost 27017 
 then
      /usr/bin/mongod --repair --dbpath /path/to/db 
      /usr/bin/mongod --fork --syslog --dbpath /path/to/db 
 fi
```

You should add cron job for the user who will run mongodb.

Comment: You definitely should **not** force MongoDB to run repair on startup; it should automatically recover from unclean shutdown using the journal. The [repair database](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/) command rebuilds the database & indexes and will result in unnecessary downtime (& perhaps an unsuccessful restart if you don't have enough space to complete the repair). You should only remove the lock file and run repair as a last resort to [recover data after unexpected shutdown](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/).